# synchronous timing in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a node.js program that makes use of the [fibrous](https://github.com/goodeggs/fibrous) library to maintain synchronous control in part of my code.

In a helper function, I need to complete a timeout, but cannot use `setTimeout()` because it will not work in the context with fibrous.

This is what I came up with instead:

```
startTimer = new Date()
startSecondTimer = new Date()
while startSecondTimer - startTimer < 10000
    startSecondTimer = new Date()
```

I'm not very comfortable with creating several thousand `Date` objects to support this workflow, but I'm not certain what a better approach here might be.

Is there a more optimal way to write a synchronous timeout-style function?

Comment: It looks like you could easily use `setTimeout` [inside a `wait`](https://github.com/goodeggs/fibrous#4-waiting-on-a-callback), or just go with [Fiber's `sleep` implementation](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers#sleep)?

Answer (score 1):

There is library for this [node-sleep](https://github.com/ErikDubbelboer/node-sleep) in C++ (fallback on Windows like your while loop). Node is not meant for such a things even more, have you notice what is this operation doing with CPU.

As a hint [How to create a sleep/delay in nodejs that is Blocking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20967006/how-to-create-a-sleep-delay-in-nodejs-that-is-blocking).