# Pushing a task to async.queue blocks express.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async.js

I have the following code.

```
var queue = require('async').queue(function(task, callback) {
  console.log("QUEUED JOB STARTED");
  require('sleep').sleep(10);
  console.log("QUEUED JOB FINISHED");
  callback();
}, 1);

router.post('/generate/', function(request, result) {
  console.log("REQUEST RECEIVED");
  queue.push({});
  result.end();
  console.log("REQUEST PROCESSED");
});
```

When the first request comes it is immediately processed. But when the next  comes just after the first one, the server waits until the queued job is finished (10 seconds) so the output is:

```
REQUEST RECEIVED
REQUEST PROCESSED
QUEUED JOB STARTED
QUEUED JOB FINISHED
REQUEST RECEIVED
REQUEST PROCESSED
QUEUED JOB STARTED
QUEUED JOB FINISHED
```

Is it possible to make Node.js enqueue and answer the second request without waiting for the first to achieve the following output?

```
REQUEST RECEIVED
REQUEST PROCESSED
REQUEST RECEIVED
REQUEST PROCESSED
QUEUED JOB STARTED
QUEUED JOB FINISHED
QUEUED JOB STARTED
QUEUED JOB FINISHED
```

Comment: It's single threaded, whenever you call `sleep`, it's going to sleep and not handle more requests, as that's what `sleep()` does, it uses a while loop to block the entire thread.

Comment: So what is the point of using async.queue if it is single threaded?

Comment: Asynchronous and multithreaded is not the same thing, when you block the thread, you block the thread, and that's what `sleep` does.

Comment: If you wan't async behaviour, use a promise or timeout

Comment: I want to have a job queue and have some control of it (read how many tasks are waiting, how many are processed at the moment etc.)

Comment: There's an answer here that creates a queue system -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20967006/how-to-create-a-sleep-delay-in-nodejs-that-is-blocking